# mean.io with mySQL

Tags: mysql, express, mean.io

Does it make sense to modify a mean.io generated mean stack project to work with mySQL instead of MongoDB?  I just started a developing job, and I'm making a project using the mean stack (I guess without the m).  Some of the projects at this company are really sloppy, and the head developer said that he wants to move in the direction of well structured projects, maybe using mean.io for organization.  However, all the company's data is currently in mySQL.  I'm trying to figure out if it would make sense to go through a mean.io created project and change it to work with mySQL, or if it's better to just build something from scratch.  I'm really new to all this stuff, so any advice (no matter how basic) would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Sonya: https://github.com/jpotts18/mean-stack-relational

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Thank you so much!  That's exactly what I needed.  It's not quite as intricate as a mean.io project, but so far I really like it.